# jaxb, skip some input tags retaining them in output

Tags: xml, parsing, input, tags, jaxb

how can I skip some tags?

I have an xml in input with some tags I'm not interested to modify, but I want to modify only some inner tags (a Java object).
The "useless" tags must be untouched.

For example,
input.xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <soap:Some>
    <ns:Echo xmlns:ns="yyyyyyyyyyyyy">
       <book>
          <title></title>
          <author>
             <name></name>
             <surname></surname> 
          </author>
          <isbn></isbn>
       </book>
    </ns:Echo>
  </soap:Some>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm interested in modify only the book object, without changing the rest of the document.
My output.xml should be, just to do some stupid editing, like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <soap:Some>
    <ns:Echo xmlns:ns="yyyyyyyyyyyyy">
       <book>
          <title></title>
          <authorName></authorName>
          <isbn></isbn>
       </book>
    </ns:Echo>
  </soap:Some>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I do this?
How can I use the JAXB annotations to solve this problem?

Thank you, I'm not experienced with JAXB.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use JAXB's `Binder` for this use case.  It is designed when you want to modify some content why maintaining the rest of the document.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html